# The webrole cycling only if Profiling and Intellitrace disabled

Tags: azure

It is weird but my webrole cycling only if the Profiling and / or Intellitrace disabled. Once I enable it it doesn't show any errors and the role publishes successfully.

Here is the information which I could find:

[image]

So when IntelliTrace enabled the project publishs successfully, otherwise the webrole cycling every time.

Comment: Have you looked at what might be in the Application event logs for details?  Is it making it completely through the OnStart for the webrole?

Comment: Event log doesn't show any errors. "Is it making it completely through the OnStart for the webrole?" how to check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blog post series at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/09/windows-azure-paas-compute-diagnostics-data.aspx walks through how to troubleshoot almost all types of role recycling issues.  I would recommend starting there and then come back if you have any specific questions about what you are finding in your logs.

By the way, the Intellitrace/Profiling is not 'fixing' your role or preventing it from crashing.  When you enable Intellitrace or Profiling those modules will detect the crash in your role and prevent it from recycling in order to preserve the diagnostics data.  So your role is behaving badly in both scenarios, you just don't see the recycling with those modules enabled.